# "maximum request length exceeded" When uploading a file to Onedrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

I'm using the sample code from "OneDriveApiBrowser" as the base for adding save to one drive support to my app. This makes use of Microsoft.Graph, I can upload small files but larger files (10Mb) will not upload and give an error "maximum request length exceeded". I get the same error in both my app and the sample code with the following line of code:

```
DriveItem uploadedItem = await graphClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(drivePath).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(newStream);
```

Is there a way to increase the maximum size of file that can be uploaded? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph will only accept small files using PUT-to-content, so you'll want to look into [creating an upload session](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession). Since you're using the Graph SDK I'd use [this test case as a guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/ff7dfdf19326aee502e7dd9e065faeaa45ce95cf/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Test/Requests/Functional/OneDriveTests.cs#L16).

Here's some  code for completeness - it won't directly compile but it should let you see the steps involved:

```
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("filename.txt").CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();

var maxChunkSize = 320 * 1024; // 320 KB - Change this to your chunk size. 5MB is the default.

var provider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, graphClient, inputStream, maxChunkSize);

// Setup the chunk request necessities
var chunkRequests = provider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
var readBuffer = new byte[maxChunkSize];
var trackedExceptions = new List<Exception>();

DriveItem itemResult = null;

//upload the chunks
foreach (var request in chunkRequests)
{
    var result = await provider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, trackedExceptions);

    if (result.UploadSucceeded)
    {
        itemResult = result.ItemResponse;
    }
}
```